# What is a proper way to communicate from my website to the .NET (C#) and vice-versa?

Tags: c#, .net, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp as a webbrowser framework in a Visual Studio C# Form application project.
I read in the CefSharp documentation that I can communicate from the .NET to my website using [CefSharp Javascript Injection](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#1-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-from-net).

```
chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.body.style.background = 'red';");
```

This line of code will change the background of my document to red.

I'm pretty sure this is not a proper way to establish a communication from the .NET to the website. (I would want for example to send data that the .NET project has to the website so the website can update the MySql database and this seems like a very fragile way to do it)

So I continued to google and I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript). It says it

> allows for communication between JavaScript and .Net.

Fair enough. I tried to read and understand what's going on but it's quite complex.
My question is: *Is this the proper way to establish a communication from my website to the .NET project and from the .NET project to my website? Is there a simpler way?*

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775 which will work for simple cases, otherwise you should bind an object as detailed in the wiki, it's not particularly complex,  look for an example at the bottom of the Async section. Sending data from you .Net app to the browser so it can make an Ajax call to update your database is a very convoluted way of doing things, just make the web requests directly.

Comment: Thanks. For the .NET --> Browser communication I'll use HttpClient to make a post request to a page and update the database (although I'm not sure about security). And for the Browser --> .NET communication I guess I'll have to do the binding.

Comment: What's kind of communication you want achieve between your application and website?

Comment: Well, I want to get the user's login data from the browser to the .NET for example. And I want to send .NET data to the browser (not necessarily to update a database). I don't know what you mean by "what kind" sorry.

Comment: Look at the postMessage example in detail first,  you can do some advanced things. Your requirements are still rather vaigue,  need some detailed examples to make specific recommendations.

Comment: Saying login data isn't specific,  we have no idea how your login system is implemented.

Comment: I understand. I looked at the PostMessage and I don't seem to even have it. Is it outdated? Anyways, I'll just go for binding, it's not a big deal. The only question I have is by binding I can communicate both ways? (.NET --> Browser and Browser --> .NET)

Comment: It's a brand new feature in version 75, if you are using the current version then you absolutely have it. You can pass a function reference from JavaScript and that translates to a IJavascriptCallback.  You'll have to be more specific than just saying both ways if you require assistance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The thing you've shown is just a communication between JavaScript and .NET

To actually communicate with the website you should use:

- Web Sockets: Real-time communication between your server and client.
- HTTP: You can use usual HTTP requests in C# to send requests and receive responses.
- JavaScript: Run the JavaScript code that will request stuff with `CefSharp` tools.

Comment: I know about HTTP requests and Ajax but what is this Web Sockets? I googled but it's not clear what I can use it for. Can I used as a simpler way to communicate back and forth between my website and the .NET?

Comment: You can get an API server with HTTP up and just use requests. You can use, for instance, Node JS server and connect with Web Sockets so that there is some realtime communication from both sides, not only when the client requests. Really depends on the purpose.

Comment: So what exactly is CefSharp tools?

Comment: Thingy mentioned in the question, bruh